# (Java) Exiting While Loop In Switch Case With Empty Line

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, blank-line

To briefly explain, I'm supposed to get the user to enter the name of the 
recipient of a message, and then get them to enter the message body, which can 
have multiple lines. If they enter a blank line, then the message body ends and 
they can select another case in the switch.

```
case 'S':
case 's':
    if(user.equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("No user logged in.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Recipient: ");
        recip = menuScan.next();

        m = new Message(user,recip);

        System.out.println("Enter message. Blank line to quit.");
        mbody = menuScan.nextLine();

        while(!mbody.equals("")) {
            mbody = menuScan.next();
            m.append(mbody);
        }

        ms.deliver(m);

        System.out.println("Messgae sent.");

    }
    break;
```

But as it is now, the while loop is skipped completely. I've tried changing `recip` to `menuScan.nextLine()`, and `mbody` to `menuScan.next()` and `.nextLine()`, but the only other thing that happens is the message body goes on forever.

I've also tried using two different Scanner objects for `recip` and `mbody`, but no luck there, either.

Comment: Use conditions instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this piece of your code

```
      System.out.println("Enter message. Blank line to quit.");
      mbody = menuScan.nextLine();

      while (!mbody.equals("")) {
           mbody = menuScan.next();
           m.append(mbody);
      }
```

changing it a bit

```
      System.out.println("Enter message. Blank line to quit.");
      mbody = menuScan.nextLine();

      while (!mbody.equals("")) {
           m.append(mbody);
           mbody = menuScan.nextLine();          
      }
```

This way the loop is executed and exited as expected.
I have used java.util.Scanner

Comment: You missed the `.next()` on `recip = menuScan.next();`. That's why the `while` loop is never entered.

Comment: Thanks! This works on the back end, but the "Recipient: " and "Enter message: " prompts display at the same time. Is there a way to separate them?

Comment: @codeslinger19 Have you tried aribeiro' solution? I can not reproduce the new situation that you describes. I get "Recipient: " first. When I type a line and press enter then a I get "Enter message:" correctly.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both. Would seeing the entire switch help?

Comment: @codeslinger19 I don't think so. As I've stated I have used java.util.Scanner. Instantiating it with System.in. Maybe you have used another class or have set specific line separators.

Comment: I'm testing it in windows btw. Line separators may differ in UNIX.

Comment: @codeslinger19 Maybe you have replaced too much .next with .nextLine in the code that we don't see. If you want to read only a character for the different options in your switch, .next is appropiate.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your `next` by `nextLine`. `next`, as the documentation states, *returns the next token if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string*, which is not what you want.

Try the following:

```
System.out.println("Recipient: ");
recip = menuScan.nextLine();

m = new Message(user,recip);

System.out.println("Enter message. Blank line to quit.");
mbody = menuScan.nextLine();

while(!mbody.equals("")) {
    m.append(mbody);
    mbody = menuScan.nextLine();
}

ms.deliver(m);

System.out.println("Messgae sent.");
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. If you don't do the append before the nextLine inside the loop, you lose the first entered line of text. You have to interchange those lines

Comment: I have detected that in my answer posted before.

Comment: @RubioRic, you're totally right! Updated my answer... On the test I did, I've noticed that also but posting it, made a typo. Thanks for pointing that out! ;)

Comment: Ok but It will not be fair if your answer is accepted instead of mine. :/